# HttpRequest POST to RESTful web service - Salesforce Apex Callout

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, salesforce

I have created a RESTful web service (C#, WCF) which implements the following interface:

```
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "?s={aStr}")]
    string Test(string aStr);
}
```

where the `Test()` method just returns whatever it was given (or a default `"test"` string) - *and also timestamps when the method was called*.

The service is **publicly available** so when I enter the url in any browser:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:41000/TestService/web/
```

It returns the json `"test"` string (or whatever might have been entered with `?s=...` at the end).

---

I want [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/) to post data to this web service.

My apex class looks like so - it gets triggered when an Object gets inserted in Salesforce:

```
public class WebServiceCallout 
{
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String name) 
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:41000/TestService/web/');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody('');

        try 
        {
            res = http.send(req);
        } 
        catch(System.CalloutException e) 
        {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When an object is inserted into Salesforce, the **Apex Jobs** section says the `sendNotification()` method was completed. But the service never picked up the POST by that method. (Note: the service IP in Remote Site Settings has been added).

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

(At this stage all I want is for Salesforce to invoke the web service - without even posting anything to it)

---

As an example I have created a sample `Console Application` that works fine POSTing to the service.

```
internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri address = new Uri("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:41000/TestService/web/");

    // Create the web request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);

    // Set type to POST
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    // Create the data we want to send  
    var postData = "";

    // Create a byte array of the data we want to send
    var byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    // Set the content length in the request headers
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

    // Write data
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }

    // Get response  
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(
        response.GetResponseStream()
        ).ReadToEnd();

    Console.Writeline(responseString);
}
```

Why doesn't my Apex Class in Salesforce callout correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I didn't specify the **Port** in Remote site settings (what!!)

The above code samples should work flawlessly (at least they do for me)

---

*Hints for whoever gets stuck with this in the future*:

In **Setup** -> **Security** -> **Remote site settings**

The service (Remote Site URL) should be in this format - where ever you host it:

```
http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:41000
```

To test the above code go to:

**[Your Name]** -> **Developer Console** -> **Debug** -> **Open Execute Anonymous Window**

and copy the following line:

```
WebServiceCallout.sendNotification('Test');
```

and click **Execute**.

Code executes and you should see an execution log (and any errors with it).